# multiple bootstrap datepicker's on the same page with extending form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

It's maybe old question to add more then date-picker's on the same page. But I have a different case here.

used library
 `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js`

Here is the script for the `datepicker`

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                keyboardNavigation: false,
                forceParse: false,
                todayHighlight: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

now multiple `date-picker` will work fine on the same page.

```
{!! Form::text('expiry_date', null, ['data-format'=>'D, dd MM yyyy', 'class'=>'form-control datepicker', 'placeholder'=>'yyyy-mm-dd']) !!}
{!! Form::text('expiry_date', null, ['data-format'=>'D, dd MM yyyy', 'class'=>'form-control datepicker', 'placeholder'=>'yyyy-mm-dd']) !!}
```

but the second `datepicker` here comes from `extending` form `script`

```
<script>
        let counter = 1;
        let limit = 10;

        function addInput(divName) {
            if (counter === limit) {
                alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
            } else {
                let newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class = "col-md-12"> <h4>Package ' + (counter + 1) + ' </h4> ...<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><div id="date-popup2" class="input-group date">{!! Form::text("expiry_date", null, ["data-format"=>"D, dd MM yyyy", "class"=>"form-control datepicker", "placeholder"=>"yyyy-mm-dd"]) !!}<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div></div>...';
                document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

When the second `datepicker` populate it dose't work. Any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're initiating the `.datepicker()`, before you have rendered the second datepicker object.

Maybe try something similar to this:

```
$(function() {
  $(this).datepicker();
  $('#date').append('<p>Other Date: <input onfocus="dateme(this);" type="text" class="datepicker"></p>')
});

function dateme(x){
  $(x).datepicker();
}
```

Just to explain what's going on here, I append a new datepicker input, which has an `onfocus=""` attribute, which calls a function containing the `.datepicker` function when the input is in focus.

Codepen Example: https://codepen.io/lthomas122/pen/XQyOMm

Comment: Yes it worked, but one thing second `datepicker` delay's and I have to click outside it once and then click it again for it to show

Comment: What might be a better approach is to change `onfocus` to `onclick`. Focus event listeners are buggy sometimes, click listeners seem to perform better, although it isn't the most ideal solution. It's probably better to have all form inputs pre-rendered on page load and before the JS is initiated if you can.

Answer (score 1):

For fast isolation

```
$('.datepick').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
            keyboardNavigation: false,
            forceParse: false,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
  // apply the rest
});
```

`this` here it will keep it isolated

Comment: still no luck still have to click outside it once and then click it again for it to show

Comment: any way I will try another `extending form` script as this one gives issue in all the fields